# How to Compress Data while invoking the S3 API from API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

We've implemented an API with **PUT** method using API Gateway which creates/updates a file with the content in the request body, it's working fine

Client --> API Gateway --> S3 Bucket

But while dealing with large size content, Invoking the S3 failing due to the size limits or API timeout (not sure abt it)

To resolve this i'm just thinking if there is any compression mechanism which can enable while invoking the S3 API from API Gateway?

Tried adding the `Accept-Encoding` header with value `gzip`, it doesn't worked.